# Pairs of hourglasses with lines and shapes between - what piece is missing?

Tags: pattern, visual

I was given this as a quick challenge, but the underlying pattern behind it eludes me entirely. What am I missing from the diagram? I don't have an answer to the question as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, could you please provide a source for this puzzle?

Comment: Hi, I am not too sure about the source since it was sent over to me by a friend. I think he got it from an IQ test online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while but I think I have it.

> The trick, I think, is thinking of these shapes as 3D objects.

> There are 2 pillars consisting of an upright and an upside-down cone. Between them is a disk shape (or coin, if you will).

> In the middle collumn we look at the shape from the front. In the left and right image we are looking at the shape from the side, so we see only one pillar because the other is behind it.

> Every row rotates the disk along a horizontal axis.

> In the left and right image we can see that the disk is tilted half way. The middle image therefore, must be image 3.

Bonus:

> If there were images to the left and right of the bottom and top images, the bottom ones would both be image 7 and the top ones would both be the two cones which don't fully come to a point but remain thick in the middle, as thick as the disk because it is upright.